# Google Sheets Formula Suggestion

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

So I have the following case.

I have a list in column A and their values in B.

I have a list in column E and their values in F.

The values of B should come from the data from F.

1)If value from A, lets's say A1, is not equal [case insensitive] to any value from the range from E1:E9999, then the B1 value should be nothing.

2) If value from A, lets's say A2, is equal [case insensitive] to a value from the E column, and that value is E4854, then B2 should be copied from F4854.

[image: Screenshot]

Kind Regards

Comment: Tags are important. Using proper tags helps your question reach the right audience. See [ask]

Comment: Hmm. Something familiar about this question; exact copy of #57886201 (no longer on display). Anyway my comment still holds: `=iferror(vlookup(lower(A1),$E$1:$F$5,2,false),"")` insert in cell B1 and copy down as many rows as needed.

Comment: @Tedinoz Do you keep track of all post numbers ;-) ?

Answer (score 2):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, E:F, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]